# JAVA window design is blank

Tags: java, swing

I am making autoclicker as a project and when i open now the window design thingy its shows me just a blank.

im trying to ask from the user to write a number in the spinner
the spinner sending it to the delay.

than you press a key to run the autoclicker and stop him

but i still didnt put the keylistener now im just trying to get output which is the delay from the spinner, not work well till now.

```
package autoclicker;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
public class auto {
static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    private Robot robot;
    private int delay;

    public void AutoClicker1() {
        try

        {
            robot = new Robot();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
public void clickMouse(int button)
{
    try {
robot.mousePress(button);
robot.delay(10);
robot.mouseRelease(button);
robot.delay(delay);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public void setDelay(int delayy)
{

this.delay = delayy;

}  

}
```

THIS IS THE MAIN

```
package autoclicker;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
public class autoclicker {


private static KeyEvent e;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("AutoClicker");

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setSize(400, 500);        

    frame.setVisible(true);

    frame.setResizable(false);



    JPanel Panel = new JPanel();
    Panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

    Panel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel AutoClicker = new JLabel("delay\r\n in ms");
    AutoClicker.setBounds(10, 80, 151, 30);
    AutoClicker.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    AutoClicker.setFont(new Font("Secular One", Font.PLAIN, 20));


    JLabel label = new JLabel("AutoClicker");
    label.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
    label.setFont(new Font("Secular One", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    label.setBounds(10, 11, 200, 57);
    Panel.add(label);


    JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
    int Delayy = (int) spinner.getValue();
    spinner.setBounds(128, 87, 69, 20);
    Panel.add(spinner);

    frame.add(Panel);

    auto clicker = new auto();

    System.out.println("----Auto Clicker----");

    System.out.println("Enter delay in ms:");

    while(Delayy==0)
    {

    }
    clicker.setDelay(Delayy);

System.out.println("Program will start in 3 seconds.");

try {
System.out.println(3);
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println(2);
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println(1);
Thread.sleep(1000);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

clicker.AutoClicker1();

for(int i = 0; i<100; i++)

{
clicker.clickMouse(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
}

}
}
```

Comment: Looks like you never add your Panel to your frame.

Comment: You should also be adding your panel to the frame's contentpane()

Comment: I dont know what frame's contentpane() does and what to add where. as i said my first project im low skilled...

Comment: Get rid of the while (delay = 0) loop. That loop will prevent all the code below it from executing.

Comment: `I dont know what frame's contentpane() does ` Start by reading the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for all the Swing basics. Start with "How to Make Frames". Download the demo code. It will show you how to better structure your class. For one thing you should NOT be using a null layout. Learn how to use "layout managers". Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to add your panel to your JFrame.

   ```
   frame.add(Panel);
   ```
2. Once you add components to your JFrame you then need to setVisibility() to true in order for it to show.

   ```
   frame.setVisible(true);
   ```

Comment: up voted this by accident, you need to write the answer so as it's consumable in one bite

Comment: Try setting the visibility of your JFrame to true after adding your panel to it.

Comment: @newbie how do you mean?

Comment: @lior JFrame needs to be revalidated AFTER components are added to it

Comment: @Pamplemousse9 just make it meaningful without having to refer back to the question, with ideally a link to an already existing  sample

Comment: @newbie okay will do, I'll know for next time. Thanks for the tips.